# How can I configure two differently formatted Console Handlers?

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Is it possible to:

--- Let the wildfly server’s logger use the Console-Handler  “CONSOLE” (configured below) to write to the wildfly console using a format defined by the “COLOR PATTERN” format.

--- Add Loggers to my server side java classes that use the Console-Handler “MY-CONSOLE” (configured below) to write to the wildfly console.  using a format defined by MY-PATTERN”?

Here is the logging subsystem definition from my wildfly 10 standalone-full.xml configuration file.
(MY-PATTERN is a silly test format makes it obvious when I have succeeded in getting it used. I'll replace it with a serious pattern if this can work. )

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">

  <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
  </console-handler>

  <console-handler name="MY-CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="MY-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <target name="System.out"/>
  </console-handler>

  <console-handler name="GOTEST-HANDLER">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="GOTEST-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
  </console-handler>

  <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
      <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <append value="true"/>
  </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
  <logger category="org.america3.gotest" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="ALL"/>
    <handlers>
      <handler name="GOTEST-HANDLER"/>
    </handlers>
  </logger>
  <logger category="com.arjuna">
    <level name="WARN"/>
  </logger>
  <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
  <logger category="sun.rmi">
    <level name="WARN"/>
  </logger>
  <root-logger>
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
      <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
  </root-logger>
  <formatter name="PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <formatter name="MY-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="MeMeMe%s%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <formatter name="GOTEST-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%n"/>
  </formatter>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: What makes you think this isn't working?

Comment: This [Logger   log    = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());] outputs text in CONSOLE format.  I can't figure out how to make my class log using MY-CONSOLE format. My goal is to let Wildfly log with CONSOLE format, and my classes log to console with MY-CONSOLE format. It that possible?

Comment: My appologies for my delay, but I didn't realize the stackoverflow website wasn't notifying me of responses ... so I'll check more often. (unless there's a way to ask to be notified)

Comment: Is `this` in the `org.america3.gotest` package? If you're seeing the message in the default format I'd assume it's in a different package.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  I auto deploy two apps on wild fly. Tapp-II.ear and Socket1.ear.with <context-root>/WSContextRoot</context-root>. The other with <context-root>/</context-root>.

Comment: oops!  I forgot you can't line feed.  org.america3.gotest is an old app that I had working using JPNL to download a Java GUI client so I could be independent of the browser.  But I've given that up so it's now irrelevant.  The app I'm working on is deployed as Socket1.ear.  And the "WSContextRoot" context root.  Is has a POJO annotated with import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint.  I'd really like to add a logger to that class that uses the MY-CONSOLE logger. But I can tell from the console my class is using the CONSOLE logger.

Comment: Instead of doing `Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())` try `Logger.getLogger("org.america3.gotest")`. If that works the `this.getClass()` is not in the `org.america3.gotest` package. That's what I was attempting to get at :)

Comment: I will try that.  But in the meantime, can you tell me why you are focused on gotest?  I seem to be missing something fundamental, because that project should be dead.  So I assume I've left an artifact behind somewhere that is independent of the goTest.ear package I've undeployed.

Comment: That worked.  Problem was that if I just named the logger with "this.getClass" the logger would descend from the root console logger.  But my standalone-full.xml config file defined a second  console logger with these attributes <logger category="org.america3.gotest" use-parent-handlers="false">. so to use it I had to use that to name my classes' logger (or use a name that descended from it).  I know it was a beginners mistake ... so I hope it helps any beginners who search for  this question.  If so, they will owe you.  Thanks for you help

Comment: Great, glad to hear it worked. Loggers work on categories and these categories are dot separated parents. So `this.getClass()` essentially does `Class.getName()` which would mean if the class isn't in the `org.america3.gotest` then it wouldn't be processed by that configured logger. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: It does now! Because once you know how, it becomes embarrassingly obvious.  Hope it helps the next newbie. Thanks again.